# spawning Ruby IRB with Tcl Expect ends tragically in a broken pipe!

Tags: ruby, tcl, pipe, expect, spawn

I am simply trying to open an irb window and enter commands. This used to work but somehow now it is broken:

```
package require Expect
set exp::winnt_debug 1
set errorInfo

set SPAWN_ID ""
set EXPECT_TIMEOUT 20

set PROMPT {irb.*[*">] }
set RUBY_HOME "C:/ruby/"
exp_spawn [file join $RUBY_HOME "bin" "ruby.exe"]\
                [file join $RUBY_HOME "bin" "irb"] "--noinspect"
set SPAWN_ID $spawn_id
puts $spawn_id

expect {
      -i $SPAWN_ID\
      -timeout $EXPECT_TIMEOUT\
      -re $PROMPT {
         set retVal 1
         puts "retVal 1"
      }
      timeout {
         set retVal 0
         puts "retVal 0"
      }
   }
match_max -i $SPAWN_ID 10000

send -i $SPAWN_ID "Hello World\r"
```

I am using WindowsXP SP3,
Ruby 1.8.7,
Tcl 8.5.10,
Expect 5.43.2, etc.

Thanks, Tom

```
irb(main):001:0> retVal 1    
write(spawn_id=]: broken pipe    
    while executing    
"send -i $SPAWN_ID "Hello World\r""    
    (file "TomSpawnRuby.tcl" line 37)
```

Comment: This functionality worked fine with Ruby 1.8.6 p26 and Tcl 8.5.9.0 and now it is broken. There must have been a bug introduced or some change in methodology. Tom

Answer (score 1):

The space searched by Expect when looking for things to match can include newlines, so it is important when using quantifiers to take steps to ensure that you don't go across lines inadvertently. For example, I suspect that the following prompt is more likely to work:

```
set PROMPT {(?n)^irb.*[*">] }
```

You could also use a more restricted set of things when parsing the varying part of the prompt:

```
set PROMPT {(?n)^irb[^\s*">]*[*">] }
```

Writing a regular expression that will match exactly what you want can take quite a bit of effort; it's a bit of an art, really, but reading the [definition of Tcl's RE syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) can help a lot. (It's not changed much over the past 10 years.)

---

Another thing to check for is whether Ruby on Windows chokes on forward slashes in filenames. If it does, you'll need to use `file nativename` to convert:

```
exp_spawn $RUBY_HOME/bin/ruby.exe [file nativename $RUBY_HOME/bin/irb] --noinspect
```

(I wouldn't bother with using `file join` in this situation.)

Comment: I always blow a synaptic tire when it comes to regular expressions; thank you for the resource and advice. I have tried your suggestions and still get the broken pipe error. It seems as though something foul and evil is killing my irb session when I performing the send command. Thank you Donal.

Comment: I suppose you could also try leaving off the `-i $SPAWN_ID`. Moreover, Expect on Windows is a gross hack anyway — the platform doesn't have a proper virtual terminal system so Expect has to use debug magic — and that might be interfering with Ruby's internals? (I don't have a suitable setup for testing that theory.)

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the syntax highlighting i would suggest that the double quote here `set PROMPT {irb.*[*">] }` needs to be escaped. `\"`  I know nothing of ruby though so correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: the RegExp seems to be adequate or I would be getting a timeout from expect.

Comment: @Tom: How do you know it's not matching too much, only triggering once the subprocess has finished?